# Word vector benchmarking

Tags: offline, nlp, benchmarking

[Vector space word representations](https://sites.google.com/site/representationlearning2013/) are useful for many natural language processing applications as they help quantify how semantically similar two words are. I trained a few vector representations of words on different datasets using [word2vec](https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/). I am looking for a program that can:

- benchmark a vector representation of words, ideally on several tasks
- compare against other vector representations (if possible as close to the state-of-the-art as possible)
- ideally, work offline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not ideal, but there is one website, http://www.wordvectors.org, which is presented in the paper "[Community Evaluation and Exchange of Word Vectors](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~mfaruqui/papers/acl14-vecdemo.pdf)" by Faruqui, Manaal  and  Dyer, Chris at ACL 2014 demo track), that allows word vector benchmarking.